# Can an unmarried man/woman become father/mother from adoption?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, puranas, manu-smriti, children

Adoption is valid in Hinduism as far as I know (Kuntibhoja adopted Kunti as his daughter).

But can an unmarried man (or woman) adopt a son and become a father from it?
Which gender can an unmarried man adopt?

Can an unmarried man's adopted child continue his family line and thus can he get rid of the debt by his ancestors that he has upon him ?

Comment: Because there is no ceremony for adoption, there is no actual way to stop this from happening.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa It is not about stopping , a man is required to have a child to continue the family line (vansh) and get rid of debt by his ancestors .Marrying and  having a child is considered as duty , and not an entertainment. I just wanted to know can an unmarried man's child continue his family line.

Comment: My point is stopping an adoption from being valid is like stopping a friendship from being valid. You can't prevent the emotions and sense of duty. Thus, yes they can.

Comment: @Aupakarana Abhibhaa A religiously sanctioned ceremony of adoption does exist in Hinduism but the pool of children fit for adoption is restricted.

Comment: Shahu, Shivaji's grandson through Shambhaji was childless on his deathbed, so on the suggestion of Tarabai (widow of Shambhaji's half-brother Rajarama), he adopted a boy whom Tarabai put forward as her grandson who was kept hidden from the world during Aurangzeb's assault on the Maratha Empire, who was then crowned as Chhatrapati Rajarama II. He was succeded by his adopted son Shahu II. Shahu II's son Pratapsingh was succeded by his adopted son Shahaji. Similiarly Ahilyabai Holkar adopted her commander-in-chief Tukoji Rao.

Comment: @AnubrataBit Can you please tell me which children are fit for adoption and what is the ceremony for adoption , with reference.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa - there is definitely a ritual & ceremony for adoption in scriptures. Putra-Sveekaram, Svayam-Dutta etc. are clearly mentioned in Manu Smriti. Which gotra the adopted son is allowed to marry is also mentioned. [scared-texts.com](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu.htm) has 12 chapters of Manu SMriti

Comment: @river, I suggest you to consult nibandhas dealing with adoption like Dattakamimamsa of Nanda-pandita (16th century scholar who also wrote commentaries on Mitakshara, Vishnu Smriti & Parashara Smriti). The ceremony of adoption is too large to be described here in comments.

Comment: @AnubrataBit Where

Comment: @mar Couldn't find a reference to those

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu09.htm #177

Comment: @mar There is mention of a weird agreement to pre-adopt a not yet born son (implying surrogacy is okay) but I couldn't see anything about a son not from the weird agreement.